# Get data of a Symfony2 Form ManyToOne Field. Not the Select widget

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I have a simple Form associated to a Doctrine Entity.

```
class MatriculaType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder
            ->add('usuario')
            ->add('active', 'checkbox', array('required' => false))
        ;
    }
```

'`usuario`' is a ManyToOne relation to a entity Named `Usuario`.

In twig, as all you will know:

```
{{ form_widget(form.usuario) }}
```

shows a html select with all the users (objects of entity Usuario).

In my particular view, I need to get the name of this user. Only that.
Or change the widget from html select to simple text.

This form is part of an arrayCollection of forms, which is embebbed in others. So the name of each User is difficult to have mapped in other variables.

The question is simple, but i dont find out a solution:

How to access to a field of the object Usuario, from the form:

I have tried

```
{{ form.usuario.vars.value }}
```

but, obviously, this returns the "usuario.id", because this is the real value stored in the database table "Matricula" as part of primary key.

```
{{ form.usuario.name ... }}
```

Doesn't work too. 'Name' doesn't exist in the array. I know that the name value is in some part inside this structure beacause I can see it in the select control.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried ->add('usuario',null,array( 'property' => 'nameOfTheProperty' )) in your action ?

Comment: With ->add('usuario',null,array( 'property' => 'name' )), the html select continues, but showing the name only (not the Usuario.toString())

Comment: Then you can also try: {{ form.vars.value.usuario }}

Comment: {{ form.vars.value.usuario }} works and give me the object Usuario. I'm happy. Thanks.

Comment: assuming that Usuario has a property $name you could use {{ usuario.vars.value.name }}